# appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01 Build Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-appcompat

I am trying to create my new Kotlin project, I have updated my Android Studio to 3.1.4 and my Gradle to 4.9 and my SDK to 28 (Repository is installed too). so I get this error on my appcompat all the time. I even changed it to alpha1 but still nothing happens.

inside my Gradle I have

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

and my log is:

> org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
>       at Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0-rc01/appcompat-v7-28.0.0-rc01.pom'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add below repository in your `build.gradle` inside buildscript -> allprojects

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to File ==>Settings==>Build,Execution,Deployment ==>Gradle ==>Remove mark of Offline work

I hope it helps you