# All dependencies faild to resolve?

Tags: java, android, gradle

My project was built and run correctly but since I updated Android Studio it gives these errors… and the offline work is unchecked.

ERRORS

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3. Open File Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.android.support:design:26.1.0. Open File Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0. Open File Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0. Open File Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0. Open File Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details


Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.1.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog
```

MY GRADLE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.radon.vitrin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation files('libs/CircleImageViewmaster/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2(1).jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
   // implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.8-beta'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Comment: Add your project level gradle . Have you added all repos in it ??

Comment: How about IP changing Alireza? Or, use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51812252/4409113

Comment: @Mohsen: heads up as your comment is being discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375313/522444). Please note the comment thread [in my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375315/522444)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it ... just add jcenter() and google() as Yuenbe said .... and then start an vpn then build the project

Answer (score 1):

In your project `.gradle` (not the app module one), you are probably missing the Google repository. That's why the dependencies cannot be found.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google() // <-- This is the line you must add
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alirezakherazani As commented in your question, could you add your project level gradle? You maybe missing something else. Also, even if not related to your question, you have dependencies appearing twice, and sometimes in different versions. You might want to delete those also.